# Why is there an overflow going from smaller to larger number?

Tags: java

A Java book I have indicates that casting from a small to larger type will occur automatically, and only going from a wider to smaller type requires a cast. If this is true, then why does the following code (where an int is exceeded by 1, thus making a long necessary), result in an overflow and not in the widening of the type?

```
int value = 2147483647 + 1; 
System.out.println(value);

=> -2147483648
```

Comment: `where an int is exceeded by 1, thus making it a long` That is not what happens. Integer overflow is what occurs

Comment: Because `int + int = int`. Try `2147483647 + 1L` and see what happens

Comment: i updated the question. i'm wondering why it doesn't automatically become a long.

Comment: `int value` is an `int` - it cannot change its type

Comment: To be a bit more verbose: `2147483647` is an `int`, as is `1`. The sum of two `int`s is again an `int`. Since `int`s are realized with a [ring arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), the calculation will overflow and wrap around.

Comment: @UnholySheep `value` is irrelevant for this question. The types of the operands is what is important.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Turing85 hu? A Ring doesn't need to overflow(R with + and * doesn't) ...

Comment: @kai I never said that every ring will overflow :) only that the concrete ring realized by `int` in Java will overflow and wrap-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java whenever you calculate two numbers, the calculation will be done using the larger type. The result will also be the larger type. But for this it doesn't matter what the values of that types is.

For example:

```
1L + 1L
```

will produce a `long` with the value of `2`.

But your example:

```
2147483647 + 1
```

will produce an `int` with the value of `-2147483648`. As both are `int` they will stay `int`.

So to make it a `long` as you want you have to:

```
2147483647 + 1L
```

to get a `long` with value `2147483648`.